# Error trying to run VirtualBox - OSX guest on Windows 7 64bit host

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, virtualbox

I have just started using VirtualBox on a 64bit version of Windows 7. So far it has been running a Ubuntu for a few weeks with no problems.

Today I tried to get OSX to work. I created a virtual machine according to [this guide](http://lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows) but so far, regardless of whether the OSX DVD is mounted or not, the machine immediately crashes with the following error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine OSX

Unknown error creating VM
(VERR_VMX_MSR_LOCKED_OR_DISABLED)
```

After googling this message, it seems this is usually caused by the host machine not supporting virtualization properly. However, I know this cannot be the case because it runs Ubuntu fine.

What is going on?

Comment: Do you have any other virtualization software running ?

Comment: Which version of Virtual Box are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike Ubuntu guest, OS X requires VT-x instructions to be enabled. Check in your BIOS is VT-x  ( aka hardware virtualization) is enabled.

Comment: Ah thanks. I thought they both required it. I checked in my BIOS and it was indeed disabled. It now works. Thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome Rupert! I faced the same problem when I was trying out OS X in VirtaulBox